# How can I use ListView.obj in filtering SOQL, or in filtering already queried data?

Tags: soql, salesforce-lightning

I am working with a Lightning:DataTable that is being populated with 1 of 3 sObject types. I would like to be able to filter the data going into the table based on the already existing List Views for the object. As this component is for LEX **and** I am not able to use an Iframe, I can't use an Enhanced List to work around this.

Looking into ListView.obj I see the tantalizing field IsSoqlCompatible. I can't seem to find any examples for ListViews being used in SOQL queries or their results. Is there some way I can utilize existing List Views to programmatically filter a query or it's results?